# Script to Restart Network Manager after Resume from Sleep

Tags: networking, suspend, hibernate

When my laptop resumes from sleep, the wifi connection doesn't resume and I have to manually restart network manager every time with `sudo service network-manager restart` from terminal.

I had a script that did that, but it prevented the PC from properly resuming from sleep so I had to remove it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to create a script in the `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` directory (or supposedly the `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` directory if you are running 15.10+) which executes that restart command on system resume. Make sure to make that script executable.

1. Create a `network_restart` file in said directory with these contents:

   ```
   case "${1}" in
     resume|thaw)
       sudo service network-manager restart
   ;;
   esac
   ```
2. Make the file executable: `sudo chmod +x network_restart`

Comment: That's a great solution. I'm using it to restart nm-applet which is losing it after suspend.

Answer (score 7):

For `systemd` on Ubuntu 16.04 you should also consider the "pre" (suspend) and "post" (resume) argument in `${1}` so that the restart executes only *after leaving system suspend*.

I also had to add a `sleep` to give the network scan enough time to complete (my best guess).

```
$ sudo cat /lib/systemd/system-sleep/network-manager-restart 
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
    case "$1" in
        post) sleep 10 ; systemctl restart network-manager ;;
    esac
fi
```

For more details read: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html

> Immediately before entering system suspend and/or hibernation
>   systemd-suspend.service (and the other mentioned units, respectively)
>   will run all executables in /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/ and pass
>   two arguments to them. The first argument will be "pre", the second
>   either "suspend", "hibernate", or "hybrid-sleep" depending on the
>   chosen action. Immediately after leaving system suspend and/or
>   hibernation the same executables are run, but the first argument is
>   now "post". All executables in this directory are executed in
>   parallel, and execution of the action is not continued until all
>   executables have finished.

Comment: "pre" and "post" are actually passed in as the first argument, `$1`, contrary to what the first paragraph says. (The code sample is correct.) I'd suggest an edit, but it's only one character :)